# why is textedit validation handler called twice?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, devexpress, textedit

This is a sample code:

```
ButtonEdit be = new ButtonEdit()
{
    DisplayFormatString = MyDisplayFrm,
    MaskType = MaskType.RegEx,
    Mask = "[-+]?([0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?",
    ValidateOnTextInput = false
};
Binding bindingValue = new Binding() { Source = PropItem, Path = new PropertyPath("Value"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(be, ButtonEdit.EditValueProperty, bindingValue);
be.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
be.Validate += be_Validate;

void be_Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Convert.ToDouble(e.Value) <= MaxVal) && (Convert.ToDouble(e.Value) >= MinVal)) return;
    MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("The value in not in the suggested range, do you want to continue?", "Min/Max Range validation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (mbr == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
        e.ErrorType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Warning;
        e.ErrorContent = "Value is not in the suggested range. Please correct.";
    }
}
```

When i change the value out of range, and change the focus, I receive the message box twice; one for changing the value, and one for changing the display, since the editor displays the value (which is double) to a proper scientific display.

How can I make the TextEdit (or in the example above the ButtonEdit) not to check for validation when changing the display? I mean it shouldn't in the first place, should it? Since the EditValue property is not changing, but only the display (the Text property).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please review this help article
[BaseEdit.InvalidValue event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_InvalidValuetopic)

AFAIK you need to handle the Validating event and within that event set e.Cancel true if the value is incorrect, then within the InvalidValue event you can provide the visual cue for the invalid entry.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please excuse this answer, just realised you are talking about the the WPF DXEditor ButtonEdit not the XtraEditors.ButtonEdit.